# on.keypress only works for first input in html

Tags: jquery

Why does this jquery work only on first input in html?

```
//check answer on ENTER keyboard press
$("body").on("keypress", "input:text[name=guesslogo]", function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {  
        $(this).siblings(".check").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

html, in this html example it only works on the last one :S

```
<article id="level-1" class="unlocked" style="position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; opacity: 1;">
    <h2>Level: 1 - 3</h2>
    <figure>
        <a href="#1" class="answered"><img src="logos/1.png" width="60" height="60" alt="1"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#2" class="logo" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="logos/2.png" width="60" height="60" alt="2"></a>
        <figcaption id="2" style="display: none;">
            <a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
            <img src="logos/2.png" width="150" height="150" alt="2">
            <a href="#" class="hint">13</a>
            <input type="text" name="guesslogo" data-lang="ge">
            <a href="#" class="check">Check</a>
            <!-- <a href="#" class="clear">Clear</a> -->
            <a href="#" class="facebookask">Ask a friend on Facebook</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#3" class="answered"><img src="logos/3.png" width="60" height="60" alt="3"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#5" class="answered"><img src="logos/5.png" width="60" height="60" alt="5"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#6" class="answered"><img src="logos/6.png" width="60" height="60" alt="6"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#8" class="answered"><img src="logos/8.png" width="60" height="60" alt="8"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#9" class="answered"><img src="logos/9.png" width="60" height="60" alt="9"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#10" class="answered"><img src="logos/10.png" width="60" height="60" alt="10"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#11" class="answered"><img src="logos/11.png" width="60" height="60" alt="11"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#12" class="answered"><img src="logos/12.png" width="60" height="60" alt="12"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#13" class="answered"><img src="logos/13.png" width="60" height="60" alt="13"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#14" class="answered"><img src="logos/14.png" width="60" height="60" alt="14"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#15" class="answered"><img src="logos/15.png" width="60" height="60" alt="15"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#16" class="answered"><img src="logos/16.png" width="60" height="60" alt="16"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#17" class="answered"><img src="logos/17.png" width="60" height="60" alt="17"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#18" class="answered"><img src="logos/18.png" width="60" height="60" alt="18"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#19" class="answered"><img src="logos/19.png" width="60" height="60" alt="19"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#20" class="answered"><img src="logos/20.png" width="60" height="60" alt="20"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#21" class="answered"><img src="logos/21.png" width="60" height="60" alt="21"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#22" class="logo" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="logos/22.png" width="60" height="60" alt="22"></a>
        <figcaption id="22">
            <a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
            <img src="logos/22.png" width="150" height="150" alt="22">
            <a href="#" class="hint">13</a>
            <input type="text" name="guesslogo" data-lang="ge">
            <a href="#" class="check">Check</a>
            <!-- <a href="#" class="clear">Clear</a> -->
            <a href="#" class="facebookask">Ask a friend on Facebook</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="#23" class="logo" style="opacity: 1;"><img src="logos/23.png" width="60" height="60" alt="23"></a>
        <figcaption id="23">
            <a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
            <img src="logos/23.png" width="150" height="150" alt="23">
            <a href="#" class="hint">13</a>
            <input type="text" name="guesslogo" data-lang="en">
            <a href="#" class="check">Check</a>
            <!-- <a href="#" class="clear">Clear</a> -->
            <a href="#" class="facebookask">Ask a friend on Facebook</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</article>
```

Comment: Please include your HTML, it's impossible to give an answer otherwise (even if I'm guessing that only your first input has name of guesslogo).

Comment: does the first input in html have the attributes type="text" name="guesslogo" ?

Comment: @ChrisDixon sure html included.

Comment: @cernunnos obviously yes :D

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fYg3m/ fiddle using your code, working perfectly. Well.. not your code... just the useful parts :P

Comment: are you sure it is not working? your .check anchors has the same href of "#"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've replicated and tested your code and it seems to work completely fine here:

http://jsfiddle.net/YeFVt/

```
$(document).on("keypress", "input:text[name=guesslogo]", function(e){
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {  
        console.log('got here');
        $(this).siblings(".check").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

It may be to do with your .check link not working properly in your live code?

The final error was to do with the `<input>` tags not being closed.

Comment: Some of them work some not, can it have something to do with the fact that I load html via ajax call? so it is not physically inside the page.

Comment: I think it's to do with your .check links having href of "#", so they're never going to go anywhere. It sounds like the .check links have a .click event attached to them, do a console.log() on this event to see if it's reaching the code.

Comment: check works fine, I've tested this extensively. Just onkeypress fails for some icons.

Comment: I did, check, on the problematic icons, I don't get console.log(e.keyCode);

Comment: Then, it may sound silly, but are you sure they're inside the <body> tag?

Comment: And, the problematic "icons", are they <input type="text" name="guesslogo" /> ?

Comment: Ok, I uploaded it here: http://gamoicani.es/logo/ click on any logo and than ENter, you will see 90% of the time it works... the rest not.

Comment: You're going to kick yourself for this. But I've just modified the HTML of your page, and by adding / to the end of your inputs, the code works fine. So you need <input /> rather than <input>

Comment: Interesting, I was about to kick myself :) but in php I have <input type="text" name="guesslogo" data-lang="<?php echo $row['logo_lang']; ?>" /> Where is the / disappearing?? :S

Comment: Not 100% sure, could you try <input></input> ?

Comment: Tried that, same, in fact even if I try <input></input> I still only see <input>. I disabled GEOKBD jquery script that changes language for input, still the same...

Comment: So strange, in fact, if you change the DOM of the broken element in any way... it works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I accept your answer and will open new topic. I tried diagnosing but no avail.

Comment: No problem, good luck, it sounds like it's going to be an odd case.