# Mystery of the trailing slash on input (disappeared!) jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've a very peculiar problem, and I cannot get hold of it.
Trailing slash on my input elements disappeared, though I'm sure (double checked) php does contain them. Something happens when jquery appends this data to html tree.

Problem can be seen here: http://gamoicani.es/logo/ if you click on logo and see input html, you will see that there is no trailing slash at the end.

But in php I've this:

```
<input type="text" name="guesslogo" data-lang="<?php echo $row['logo_lang']; ?>" />
```

I even tried `<input></input>` but result is the same.

I also disabled knob and kbd jquery plugins on these inputs but something is not right and it simply doesn't work.

I checked my ajax call:

```
function create_views(level) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "actions.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: "show_level=" + level,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data){
                views[level] = '<li data-level="' + level + '">' + data + '</li>';

                //Count completed tasks
                completed_calls++;

                //if last level is loaded-called append and activate slider
                if (levels == completed_calls) {
                    //append views to container
                    console.dir($(".slides_container").append(views.join(' ')));
                    //activate slider
                    unislider = $(".slides_container").dpUniSlider({
                        //loop: false,
                        draggable: false
                    });
                    //Activate Georgian keyboard for some logos
                    $("input[data-lang=ge]").GeoKBD();

                    //Activate progress bar
                    update_level_progress_bar();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Did console.dir on views and / is there! So it must be during append something goes wrong... I'm running out of ideas to check...

Why do I care about trailing slash?

[on.keypress only works for first input in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062255/on-keypress-only-works-for-first-input-in-html)

```
//check answer on ENTER keyboard press
$("body").on("keypress", "input:text[name=guesslogo]", function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {  
        $(this).siblings(".check").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

This doesn't work correctly!

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why do care about a trailing slash? Are you looking at your DOM with Firebug or Developer Tools or something? You do know they don't show the self-closing `/`, right? If it's in your HTML, it won't show up in the DOM representation by the browser

Comment: The slash is not going to make any difference.

Comment: You don't need to close `<input>` tags.  Their content model is "empty". Self-closing tags are meaningless in HTML anyway.

Comment: @Ian I care because of this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062255/on-keypress-only-works-for-first-input-in-html

Comment: @epascarello I updated OP, can you check it? reason is in the end.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze What do you mean by "if you click on logo and see input html"? What are you doing to "see input html"?

Comment: @SandroDzneladze And by the way, use `e.which`, not `e.keyCode`. jQuery normalizes the key code of the event into `which`.

Comment: It fails on the second one, works on the first.

Comment: @epascarello What fails/works? Pressing enter in the textbox?

Comment: @SandroDzneladze Also, is there a reason you're using `keypress` and not `keydown`?

Comment: @Ian, yes an enter key in the textbox on the second icon will fail.

Comment: @epascarello Woah, it was just working for me I thought. It works for me for all of the icons **except** the second one (the purple one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned before, it has nothing to do with the slash.

Change the code to use document instead of body with keydown

```
$(document).on("keydown","input[name='guesslogo']",function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {  
        $(this).siblings(".check").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

Your code will work with this change.

Comment: (helping your argument, although I don't understand why `document` would be different from `"body"`) From the jQuery docs for `keypress` - "If key presses anywhere need to be caught (for example, to implement global shortcut keys on a page), it is useful to attach this behavior to the `document` object. Because of event bubbling, all key presses will make their way up the DOM to the `document` object unless explicitly stopped."

Comment: +1 though this might be worth moving to the original question :)  Also worth noting that this should probably be done with classes rather than with names.

Comment: Did body-> document fixed the issue or, keydown? most importantly, why? :) it works perfectly though...

Comment: Do you know what the difference is between `document` and `"body"` here? Shouldn't the event just as regularly pass through `<body>` as it does it `document`?

Comment: With body one of the children elements or itself needs focus for it to reliably capture the event. Looks like something is causing a blur to happen so it is not being focused. I did not spend the time to really track down the root cause, just know basic fixes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have closing slashes on input tags. They don't contain items within them and are represented as a single tag.

This:

> I even tried `<input></input>` but result is the same.

is actually completely incorrect.  There's never a closing tag for [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input)

On another note, jQuery doesn't append exactly what you post, it parses it and then adds it as semantically correct HTML.

For instance `$().append` will append the same thing for `"<div>"`, `"<div/>"`, and `"<div></div>"`

Also tools like Chrome dev tools will show the input without the / even if you type it explicitly into source.

Try inspecting the input here: http://jsfiddle.net/f7USH/ and you'll see that the element is added as an input with a slash but appears without it in devtools.

Comment: This problem is related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062255/on-keypress-only-works-for-first-input-in-html if I don't have trailing slash at the end of input keypress doesn't work.

Comment: uh, in the solution given back to you for the answer to that question the inputs do not have trailing slashes : http://jsfiddle.net/YeFVt/  I don't see anyone who suggested that you need slashes.

Comment: I did. This came from the DOM being changed and the solution magically working, so it was more of a case of that.

Comment: Both Firebug and Chrome Developer Tools don't show the `/` for self-closing elements. IE Developer Tools does though

Answer (score 1):

Self-closing tag syntax, in modern HTML, is just [syntactic sugar for people addicted to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5/3558200#3558200).

When you use a DOM viewer to look at a document, you see a serialisation of the DOM to HTML (not the original source code).

Since the slash is entirely optional, your viewer doesn't render it.

> Why do I care about trailing slash?

That code not working has nothing to do with the trailing slash.

Comment: IE Developer Tools renders it. Actually, it seems to render a `/` for any element without any inner content, even `div`s or `textarea`s

Comment: The viewer being used by the OP ("your viewer") does not.

Comment: I wasn't trying to argue against anything, I was just adding information. ben336 already pointed out this Developer Tools behavior anyways, and I provided the same comment